# Is Xcode with Swift on Mavericks possible?

Tags: xcode, swift

My school computers have OS X 10.9.4 on them but they don't want to update them because of incompatibility with their Music class software. From what I see on Apple's website Xcode 6.4 and 6.3.1 both need Yosemite. Is there another version of Xcode that I can download somewhere so I can code using Swift?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A quick search for [Xcode at the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) give you the answer. With the OS X version 10.9.4, you are able to install Xcode 6.2 and below.

On Xcode 6.2 you can code in Swift, but I'm afraid is not the latest Swift version.

[This is the table where you can find out the requested information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_5.0_.2B_.28with_arm64_support.29).

Comment: You can download the older versions (such as 6.2) from the Apple Developer website. https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

Comment: I didn't even think of checking the developer website.